# SQL connection with windows login form

Tags: c#, sql

l really a want a help on this code, trying to connect SQL with C# in making a windows form to fill password and username, I dt.Fill(); gave an error, non-innovocable member... I would like to know what I should do about the code?

```
namespace Homeworkc
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         this.Close();
         Application.Exit();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\courageboy\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Homeworkc\Data.sdf");
         SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*)From Login where username='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Fill();

         if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
         {
            this.Hide();
            Displayform df = new Displayform();
            df.Show();
         }

         else 
         {
            MessageBox.Show("please you have enter a wrong Username or Password");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Note: You should only be storing hashed passwords, so your password column should contain only gibberish.  If it doesn't you have a problem.  This code is also a huge SQL Injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

Using `SqlDataAdapter` you need to Fill `DataTable` like:

```
sda.Fill(dt);
```

This uses method [`SqlDataAdapter.Fill Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx)

With your statements:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Fill(); //this one
```

This `DataTable` is independent of your `SqlDataAdapter`, you need to call `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` method to fill the `DataTable`.

As a side not consider using [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) in your code, your current code is open to [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @ Habib, thanks alot,the rest of the guys you are all inspiration to all